# Json schema for recursive key

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

json data as given and have the names of the students in multiple instance like 100 (only 3 given). So, is there a way to give a `#defs` for a key and value to simplify the schema?

```
{
  "student_id": {
    "Alice": 0,
    "Bob": 1,
    "Charlie": 2,
    "Derek": 3,
    "Emily": 4,
    "Florence": 5
  },
  "project": {
    "Alice": "Science",
    "Bob": "Math",
    "Charlie": "Science",
    "Derek": "Science",
    "Emily": "Math",
    "Florence": "Math"
  },
  "summer_camp": {
    "Alice": true,
    "Bob": false,
    "Charlie": true,
    "Derek": false,
    "Emily": true,
    "Florence": false
  },
  "Data":[
    "student_id",
    "project",
    "summer_camp"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the property names in a reusable definition:

```
{
  "$defs": {
    "property_names_students": {
      "propertyNames": {
        "enum": [
          "Alice",
          "Bob",
          ...
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "student_id": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/property_names_students",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    },
    "project": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/property_names_students",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "enum": ["Science", "Math", ... ]
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: "additionalProperties", not working to validate the value integer as given,  I put string there still the validation passed